# How to do collision detection in SVG

Tags: javascript, svg, collision-detection, collision

Making a spaceship game when meteor hits spaceship= game over. How do I do collision detection in SVG?

Below is the code I have. I have the meteors coming from different directions and I want the meteors to collide with the rocket ship. The rocket ship coordinates I know which is in the code. The meteors are random coming from different directions on the screen so I do not have coordinates. I looked into paths and other ways to get the coordinates. But it seems with animation there is not a way I can think of the capture the coordinates and create a collision detection. Any help is appreciated.

```js
"use strict"

let draw = SVG('drawing');


draw.size(800, 650); //Draws the canvas size, I made it this size so the user doesn't have to scroll screen

/* Calling of functions*/


Background(draw, 0, 0);
cloud(draw,80,80);
//starPower(draw, 0,0);



/* Event Listener when screen is click game starts*/
document.addEventListener("click", startGame) //event listener when user clicks on screen
let score = 0;

/*Function start game where items come and title disappears*/
function startGame() {
  title.hide(); //title disappears
  author.hide(); //Author name disappears
  start.hide(); // click anywhere to start disappears
  controls.hide(); //controls to move spaceship
  shootTLMeteors(); //Meteors start shooting from upper left corner
  shootTRMeteors(); //Meteors start shooting from upper right corner
  shootBLMeteors(); //Meteors start shooting from lower left corner
  shootBRMeteors(); //Meteors start moving from lower right corner


/*Score function as player is still alive, score increases*/
let timer = setInterval(addscore, 1000);
    
    function addscore(){
        score= score++
        return score;   
    }
    

    
/*When the game is clicked then the score comes up*/   
let scoretext = draw.text("Score:" + timer ).move(100, 10).font({
  family: 'Helvetica',
  size: 30,
  anchor: 'middle',
  leading: '1.5em'
});
}

/*End of startGame function*/

/*Function to create star powerup**NEED TO CALL AND PUT RANDOM WHEN METEORS START***/
function starPower(){

let star = draw.polygon('100,10 40,180 190,60, 10,60 160,180').fill('red').stroke({ width: 1 }).animate(100000).move(Math.floor((Math.random() * x) + 800), Math.floor((Math.random() * y) + 650)).path('M 10 621 L 766 92 ');//draws red star

}

function Background(draw, x, y) {
  let bg = draw.rect(innerWidth, innerHeight).move(50, 0);
  //draw background of game

  bg.fill("#33F9FF");
  //inital blue background for starting
  /*switch (score) {
      case 10: bg.fill("#33E6FF")
          break;
      case 15: bg.fill("#33C7FF")
          break;
      case 20: bg.fill("#33B5FF")
          break;
      case 25: bg.fill("#3399FF")
          break;
      case 30: bg.fill("#3364FF")
          break;
      case 40: bg.fill("#2F5BE9")
          break;
      case 50: bg.fill("#2951D0")
          break;
      case 55: bg.fill("#264CC6")
          break;
      case 60: bg.fill("#2343AC")
          break;
      case 65: bg.fill("#1F3C99")
          break;
      case 70: bg.fill("#1C3585")
          break;
      case 75: bg.fill("#192E75")
          break;
      case 80: bg.fill("#182B6A")
          break;
      case 85: bg.fill("#132256")
          break;
      case 90: bg.fill("#101D49")
          break;
      case 95: bg.fill("#0D1738")
          break;
      case 100: bg.fill("#080E23")
          break;
      default: bg.fill("green") 
          break;

  }
*/
}

/*Meteors shootings from directions function*/


function shootTLMeteors() {
  setInterval(function() {
    topLeftMeteor(draw, 800, 800);
  }, 3000);
    
}
  /*This function makes meteors shoot from the top left side of the canvas to diagnoal opposite in 3 seconds increments*/



function shootTRMeteors() {
  setInterval(function() {
    topRightMeteor(draw, 800, 800);
  }, 3000);
}

  /*This function makes meteors shoot from the top right side of the canvas to diagnoal opposite in 3 seconds increments*/

function shootBLMeteors() {
  setInterval(function() {
    bottomLeftMeteor(draw, 800, 800);
  }, 3000);
}

  /*This function makes meteors shoot from the bottom left side of the canvas to diagnoal opposite in 3 seconds increments*/


function shootBRMeteors() {
  setInterval(function() {
    bottomRightMeteor(draw, 800, 800);
  }, 3000);
}
  /*This function makes meteors shoot from the bottom right side of the canvas to diagnoal opposite in 3 seconds increments*/

/* The creation of the path of the meteors from upper left side*/

function topLeftMeteor(d, x, y) {
  let meteor = d.image('https://clip2art.com/images/asteroid-clipart-5.png', 80, 80);

meteor.animate(10000).move(Math.floor((Math.random() * x) + 600), Math.floor((Math.random() * y) + 1000));

  //Inserted image of meteor which will be used to avoid, coordinates are always random from 1-800 which is the canvas size
}
    
    
function topRightMeteor(d, x, y) {
  let meteor = d.image('https://clip2art.com/images/asteroid-clipart-5.png', 80, 80);

  meteor.animate(10000).move(Math.floor((Math.random() * x) + 600), Math.floor((Math.random() * y) + 1000));
  //Inserted image of meteor which will be used to avoid, coordinates are always random from 1-800 which is the canvas size
    
}
    
function bottomRightMeteor(d, x, y) {
  let meteor = d.image('https://clip2art.com/images/asteroid-clipart-5.png', 80, 80);

  meteor.animate(10000).move(Math.floor((Math.random() * x) + 800), Math.floor((Math.random() * y) + 650));
  //Inserted image of meteor which will be used to avoid, coordinates are always random from 1-800 which is the canvas size
    
}


function bottomLeftMeteor(d, x, y) {
  let meteor = d.image('https://clip2art.com/images/asteroid-clipart-5.png', 80, 80).move(-20,0);

  meteor.animate(10000).move(Math.floor((Math.random() * x) + 800), s
  //Inserted image of meteor which will be used to avoid, coordinates are always random from 1-800 which is the canvas size
    
}

function meteor(){
    let x = randomVal(0,800);
    let y =randomVal(0,800);
    
    let meteor = d.image('https://clip2art.com/images/asteroid-clipart-5.png', 80, 80).move(x,y);
}

function radomVal(min,max){
    return Math.floor((Math.random() * max) + min); 
}

function cloud(d,x,y){
// initialize the loop
let clx = 0;
let cly = 0; 

while (x < 50) {
  draw.image('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/95/Cartoon_cloud.svg').fill("red").move(clx * 50, cly * 50);
  clx = clx + 1;
}
// now the loop condition and the code block for the pattern


}



  //console.log();

  /*
    if(meteor.attr("x")>=ship.attr("x") && meteor.attr("x")+10<=ship.attr("x")){
        console.log("collide");
    }
if(meteor.attr("y")>=ship.attr("y") && meteor.attr("y")+10<=ship.attr("y")){
        console.log("collide");
    }
//}

*/


let moveY = 300;
let moveX = 300;
/* Inital coordinates of X and Y to move ship*/
let ship = draw.image('https://i.pinimg.com/originals/bd/7c/95/bd7c9566f984f16a696a750711fcb8c0.png', 200, 200);
ship.move(moveX, moveY); /*Inserted image of spaceship which will be used to control*/



document.addEventListener("keypress", ShipControl)

function ShipControl() {

  if (event.key == "w") {
    moveX = moveX;
    moveY = moveY - 10;
    ship.move(moveX, moveY);
    /*W key moves the spaceship towards the top of screen*/
  }

  if (event.key == "w" && moveY == 0) {
    moveX = moveX;
    moveY = moveY + 10;
    ship.move(moveX, moveY);
    /*W key moves the spaceship towards the top of screen when it hits top of screen it stops moving*/
  }



  if (event.key == "s") {
    moveX = moveX;
    moveY = moveY + 10;
    ship.move(moveX, moveY);
    /*S key moves the spaceship towards the bottom of screen*/
  }
  if (event.key == "s" && moveY == 550) {
    moveX = moveX;
    moveY = moveY - 10;
    ship.move(moveX, moveY);
    /*S key moves the spaceship towards the bottom of screen when it hits bottom of the screen it stops moving*/
  }


  if (event.key == "a") {
    moveY = moveY;
    moveX = moveX - 10;
    ship.move(moveX, moveY);
    /*A key moves the spaceship towards the left of screen*/
  }

  if (event.key == "a" && moveX == 0) {
    moveY = moveY;
    moveX = moveX + 10;
    ship.move(moveX, moveY);
    /*A key moves the spaceship towards the left of screen when it hits left of the screen it stops moving*/
  }


  if (event.key == "d") {
    moveY = moveY;
    moveX = moveX + 10;
    ship.move(moveX, moveY);
    /*D key moves the spaceship towards the right of screen*/
  }

  if (event.key == "d" && moveX == 700) {
    moveY = moveY;
    moveX = moveX - 10;
    ship.move(moveX, moveY);
    /*D key moves the spaceship towards the right of screen when it hits right of the screen it stops moving*/
  }

}

let title = draw.text("Meteor Rush").move(400, 50).font({
  family: 'Helvetica',
  size: 100,
  anchor: 'middle',
  leading: '1.5em'
}); //Creates title of Meteor Rush
let author = draw.text("Created By: Fran").move(400, 200).font({
  family: 'Helvetica',
  size: 30,
  anchor: 'middle',
  leading: '1.5em'
}); //Creates line of Creator

let start = draw.text("Click Anywhere To Start").move(400, 600).font({
  family: 'Helvetica',
  size: 30,
  anchor: 'middle',
  leading: '1.5em'
}); //Creation of Click Anywhere to Start

let controls = draw.text("Controls: W=Up, S=Down, A=Left, D=Right").move(400, 500).font({
  family: 'Helvetica',
  size: 30,
  anchor: 'middle',
  leading: '1.5em'
}); //Controls
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/svg.js/2.7.1/svg.js"></script>
```